# Combining svyimputationLists

Tags: r, survey, imputation

I am working with the Survey of Consumer Finances dataset and am looking to do analysis across years. My initial thought is to combine them into the same svyimputationList, but my attempts don't seem to actually combine the data. they remain as different lists within a larger svyimputationList. There could be other ways to do analysis across years (I mainly looking to be able to run some regressions) so those answers are also welcome.

The class of the scf_design sets are "svyimuptationList".

Below is the code I have used in order to gather the datasets and my attempt to combine.

```
library(lodown)
library(survey)
library(mitools)
library(plyr)

        scf_cat <-
  get_catalog( "scf" ,
               output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" ) )
 # 2016 only
scf_cat_16 <- subset( scf_cat , year == 2016 )
#2013 only
scf_cat_13 <- subset( scf_cat , year == 2013 )
 # download the microdata to your local computer
scf_cat_16 <- lodown( "scf" , scf_cat_16 )
scf_cat_13 <- lodown( "scf" , scf_cat_13 )
 #setup the data to control for the survey style and MI
scf_imp_16 <- readRDS( file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" , "scf 2016.rds" ) )
 scf_rw_16 <- readRDS( file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" , "scf 2016 rw.rds" ) )
 scf_imp_13 <- readRDS( file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" , "scf 2013.rds" ) )
 scf_rw_13 <- readRDS( file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" , "scf 2013 rw.rds" ) )
 #APPLYING THE WEIGHTS TO THE DATA#####
scf_design_16 <- 
  svrepdesign( 
    weights = ~wgt , 
    repweights = scf_rw_16[ , -1 ] , 
    data = imputationList( scf_imp_16 ) , 
    scale = 1 ,
    rscales = rep( 1 / 998 , 999 ) ,
    mse = FALSE ,
    type = "other" ,
    combined.weights = TRUE
  )
 scf_design_13 <- 
  svrepdesign( 
    weights = ~wgt , 
    repweights = scf_rw_13[ , -1 ] , 
    data = imputationList( scf_imp_13 ) , 
    scale = 1 ,
    rscales = rep( 1 / 998 , 999 ) ,
    mse = FALSE ,
    type = "other" ,
    combined.weights = TRUE
  )


scf_design <- rbind(scf_design_16,scf_design_13)
```

Comment: Well if you are creating lists that you want to piece together this cannot be done with `rbind` (row bind), appending a list would be done with `list.append(.data, ...)`. But I have no idea what `svredesign()` does, so maybe show us the class and structure of `scf_design_13/16`

Comment: Also please include the libraries being used.

Comment: hi, the imp_13 and imp_16 lists each have data frames in them.  you'll want to stack each of them, respectively.  rw_13 and rw_16 are already data.frame objects, also stack those.  ultimately you want to construct something like this  http://asdfree.com/statistically-significant-trends-with-multiple-years-of-complex-survey-data.html but this example is `svydesign` where scf is `svrepdesign`

Comment: hello, I have been dabbling around with this for a bit and believe that I am close doing some subsetting of the variables in order to stack the imputations. The one thing I am unsure of is how to work with the weight file in order to ensure that maintains its integrity with the svydesign. This comes from the fact that the dataframe is labeled weight1,weight2,...

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that I have come up with after looking into what Anthony Damico commented:

It follows the form of stacking the data frames within the list of imputations and the replicate weight files to ultimately combine them to the svyimputationList.

```
scf_cat <-
  get_catalog( "scf" ,
               output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" ) )

yearslist <- list(10,13,16)
y1<- NULL
y2<- NULL
y3<- NULL
y4<- NULL
y5<- NULL
imp <- NULL
rw <- NULL
#loop to load in the desired years and assign the weights
for (i in 1:length(yearslist)){

  year <- yearslist[i]
  fullyear <- as.numeric(paste0("20",year))
  df1 = scf_cat[FALSE,]


  df1 <- subset( scf_cat , year == fullyear )
  df2 <- lodown( "scf" , df1)

  scf_imp <- readRDS( file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" , paste0("scf ",fullyear,".rds" ) ))

  for( i in 1:length(scf_imp)){

    scf_imp[[i]][["year"]] <- fullyear

    scf_imp[[i]] <- select(scf_imp[[i]],c("yy1","one","year","wgt","edcl","hhsex","age","married","kids","lf","lifecl",
                                          "networth","racecl4","racecl","occat1","income","norminc","wsaved",
                                          "spendmor","spendless","late","late60","hpayday","bshopnone",
                                          "bshopgrdl","bshopmodr","checking","hcheck",
                                          "saving","hsaving","mmda","cds","irakh","anypen","vehic","hvehic",
                                          "own","nown","newcar2","newcar1","veh_inst","hveh_inst","x7543","x7540",
                                          "x2206","x2209","x2210","x2211","x2212","x2213","x2219"))

  }

  scf_rw <- readRDS( file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" , paste0("scf ",fullyear," rw.rds" ) ))

  #piecing together the dataframes
  #figure out a loop for this
  y1<- rbind(scf_imp[[1]],y1)
  y2<- rbind(scf_imp[[2]],y2)
  y3<- rbind(scf_imp[[3]],y3)  
  y4<- rbind(scf_imp[[4]],y4)
  y5<- rbind(scf_imp[[5]],y5)

  rw <- rbind(scf_rw,rw)


  #include or exclude incrimental saving
  assign(paste0("scf_imp_",year),scf_imp)
  assign(paste0("scf_rw_",year),scf_rw)


  assign(paste0("scf_design_",year),
         svrepdesign(
           weights = ~wgt ,
           repweights = scf_rw[ , -1 ] ,
           data = imputationList( scf_imp ) ,
           scale = 1 ,
           rscales = rep( 1 / 998 , 999 ) ,
           mse = FALSE ,
           type = "other" ,
           combined.weights = TRUE
         ))

  rm(df1)
  rm(df2)
  rm(scf_imp)
  rm(scf_rw)
}

#piecing together the imputations
imp <- list(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)

#creating the design using the set of 3 years
design_full <- svrepdesign(
  weights = ~wgt ,
  repweights = rw[ , -1 ] ,
  data = imputationList( imp ) ,
  scale = 1 ,
  rscales = rep( 1 / 998 , 999 ) ,
  mse = FALSE ,
  type = "other" ,
  combined.weights = TRUE
)
```